# There is no airbnb when I create eslint with yarn

Tags: eslint, airbnb-js-styleguide

Airbnb does not exist when I create eslint with yarn.
Only two options [standard, X0]
how do I see airbnb?

`yarn create @eslint/config`

```
How would you like to use ESLint?
- To check syntax, find problems, and enforce code style

What type of modules does your project use?
- JavaScript modules (import/export)

Which framework does your project use?
- React

Does your project use TypeScript?
- Yes

Where does your code run?
- Browser
- Node

How would you like to define a style for your project?
- Use a popular style guide

Which style guide do you want to follow?
> standard:...
> X0:...
```